# Send a notification (or just vibrate) to phone via ADB/shell

Tags: adb, notifications, shell, ssh, vibration

I would like to be able to send some kind of notification to my android using a remote shell script (SimpleSSHD running as root, so basically the same as an adb shell).

On an iOS device I can use the commands `cvibrate` to make the device vibrate and `sbalert` to display a notification via SSH. I would like to do the same, but on android.

It would be great if it could be an actual notification like any other app would invoke, but a way to just vibrate it would suffice aswell if both isn't possible on android.

This seems like a very simple task, but I've not been able to find a solution...

Comment: For Termux there is the [Termux-vibrate](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-vibrate) and the [Termux-notification](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-notification) package. Not sure how make those calls available in a stand-alone sshd. Also relevant: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207411

Comment: @Robert Looking at the source code of [NotificationAPI.java](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/termux/api/NotificationAPI.java) and [VibrateAPI.java](https://github.com/termux/termux-api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/termux/api/VibrateAPI.java) - This is an app-based solution (that I'd like to avoid) that only works with Termux, using the `Termux API` app to control notifications/vibration/etc.

Comment: @Robert - HOWEVER: I've tried `echo 200 > /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable` from the comments of the Q you linked: And it worked! I'd like to keep the qusetion open because I'd prefer notifications or some sort of alert/pop-up on the screen aswell, but if nothing else is possible without the Termux app + API that would be good enough of an answer for me. (Note for others: That command requires root (at least over SSH), which for me is not an issue though.)

Comment: Also see [Notify4Scripts](https://github.com/halnovemila/Notify4Scripts)

Answer (score 9):

Use cmd notification:

```
cmd notification post [flags] <tag> <text>
```

If you are root notification will not be displayed:

```
su -lp 2000 -c "cmd notification post -S bigtext -t 'Title' 'Tag' 'Multiline text'"
```

Comment: Nice. I was able to post notification with root. It still showed as being posted from Shell though. Android 10 on a OnePlus 6 using Termux.

Comment: What is even more annoying for me: I found no way to send without triggering the notification sound

Comment: Which Android versions does/should this work on?

Comment: @confetti Android 10: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7647f1d1b8189a6d7ab321ce67f60d115cb3598b

Comment: Simple example: `adb shell cmd notification post -S bigtext -t 'Title' 'Tag' 'Multiline text'`

Answer (score 6):

You can setup a Task in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) which you can invoke from command-line. The task can be setup with actions of your liking in combination, such as show a notification and [vibrate with XYZ pattern](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/ah_vibrate_pattern.html). When setting up a task in Tasker, setup the action like this: Alert → Notify

Fill up the fields as you like. Make sure to enable *Allow External Access* setting under Preferences →  Misc, accessible from three-dots line on the right edge of top bar in Tasker's homescreen.

As for invoking the task from command line, run:

```
su -c am broadcast -a net.dinglisch.android.taskerm.ACTION_TASK --es "task_name" "YOUR_TASK"
```

Replace YOUR_TASK with your task's name.

Tip: you can setup Tasker to show text of your liking in your notification  by a bit more tricks. Setup a task to watch for a file for changes and assign an action to change the value of a tasker variable to the contents of that file. In your aforesaid vibration/notification task, when filling up the field for "text", assign that local variable instead. So next time, when invoking the task, change the contents of the file for a custom text notification before sending that command.

Tip2: it is also possible that send variable directly to a task using command-line, but I don't have much experience with it so you've got to ask uncle web.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, +1 especially for the tips. I would much prefer a solution that doesn't require an external application. Seems not possible though, but I'll probably go with `notify4scripts` since it seems more lightweight and easier to customize.

Comment: @confetti every notification is sent by an app, so there isn't a way to create otherwise. System apps don't provide a method to send notification from commandline, so a 3rd party app is needed. I once tried to create some surfaces/windows directly dealing with SurfaceFlinger, but due to lack of knowledge couldn't figure out where to proceed. I don't think creating notifications natively without involving Android's Java framework would be a feasible solution (if possible at all). There is a mishmash of APIs and IPCs, at lower level closed source as well.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the input. I guess I'll just stick with the vibrate-only solution then as it's the most simple and sufficient for my alert system. Maybe you want to add that to your answer so I can accept it? I'm sure the app-based solution will be helpful to others aswell.

Comment: @confetti yes the app based solution is helpful, I have been using it since long to send notifications from Linux environment. Notify4Scripts has a wiki page: https://github.com/halnovemila/Notify4Scripts/wiki and mentioned in an answer already: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155338/how-to-send-notifications-to-an-android-device-from-a-pc-via-usb/173562#173562. So I don't think it needs any further input. You may please self answer your question if you want to.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Oh, thank you, I was talking to Firelord though asking to add the `echo 200 > /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable` command to the answer because both solutions are great and would be ideal for different scenarios and people so I feel like both deserve to be the accepted answer.