# Send A Notification To Android 9 Device Via ADB/shell/Script

Tags: adb, notifications

wondering if it's possible to send a notification to an Android 9 device when a script finishes?  I have a custom Magisk script that runs on first boot for my rom releases that does some things like set some useful device settings and such and I have exactly what I want for Android 10+, but I can't seem to find anything similar for Android 9

I found and use this for Android 10+ and it works great
[Send Notifications- Android 10+](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221089/send-a-notification-or-just-vibrate-to-phone-via-adb-shell/232091#232091)

Working Android 10+ Command:
`su -lp 2000 -c "cmd notification post -S bigtext -t 'A-Team Notification' 'Tag' 'Post Boot Install Script Complete, Enjoy!!'"`

My problem is, I'm now working on an Android 9 device and obviously the Android 10 command does not work on Android 9.  Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same thing without having to use a 3rd party app?

Comment: You need to use a third party app. There's no other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a notification (or just vibrate) to phone via ADB/shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221089/send-a-notification-or-just-vibrate-to-phone-via-adb-shell)